# If cell A2:A1000 contains any letter or number, put today's date on same row

Tags: excel, vba

working on the project at work and tried to search but can't find any answers.

Like the title says, if cell a2 to a1000 contains any letter or number, I would like to input today's date on row E (same row but today's date 4 rows over on column E).  Please see example of what I want picture below.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: So if any special character is found you want to do nothing right

Comment: `=if(len(a2)>0,today(),"")`, copy down

Comment: @nutsch i'm hesitant to think this is what OP needs. If so, it almost seems like effort was put in to over complicate the question. OP can you clarify, are just just looking for `non-blank` cells or are you looking for cells that do not contain any `special characters`

Comment: If a2 to a1000 contains any letter, symbol, or number, I would like it to show todays date on coloumn E on same row.   If no letter, symbol, or numbers, I would like it to be blank.     I tried the code below; however, it did not generate today's date.  I have changed the "sheet1" to "Mail Merge Sheet" because that is the name of my sheet.   Thank you everyone for help.

Comment: Help please.   I really need to get this working.  Saved as xlsm and still not working?  Do I paste the code into sheet1 or create a module and paste the codes?

Answer (score 1):

## Not Empty Date

```
Sub NotEmptyDate()

    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet1"
    Const cCol1 As String = "A"
    Const cCol2 As String = "E"
    Const cFirst As Long = 2
    Const cLast As Long = 1000

    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        For i = cFirst To cLast
            If Not IsEmpty(.Range(cCol1 & i)) Then
                .Range(cCol2 & i) = Date
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this small VBA macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("A2:A1000")
        If r.Value <> "" Then r.Offset(0, 4) = Date
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This worked; however, I had to press the macro button to generate dates.  I would be awesome if I don't have to press any button and when I put words in cell A, it automatically generates the today's date instantly.  Please help. Thanks.

Comment: If you want that, you can copy the code to the worksheet module under the Worksheet_Change name